# Navigation component и Viewmodel

Tags: android, viewmodel, navigation

Допустим, есть фрагмент с вьюмоделью и диалог. Из диалога посредством навигации в фрагмент передается некоторое значение. Каким образом при возврате во фрагмент можно вызвать вьюмодель, чтобы передать туда это значение? Либо в диалоге вызывать вьюмодель и передавать? Как принято действовать в таком случае?

Comment: неясна суть. пожалуйста, уточните, а лучше конкретизируйте задачу.

Comment: Задача - передать значение из диалога во вьюмодель, которая приписана к фрагменту, после возврата из диалога посредством navigate. Возможно, есть какой-нибудь колбэк при переходе по графу навигации?

Comment: Есть мысль, что во фрагменте можно проверять аргументы на определенный ключ и при его наличии вызывать вьюмодель, но по-моему - это костыль.

Comment: viewModel должна быть всегда инициализирована, поэтому не совсем понятно что значить "при его наличии вызывать вьюмодель". в задаче всего 1 фрагмент или 2 ? если 1 - то до сих пор не понимаю проблемы. если 2, и вам надо чтобы данные одной ВьюМодели были на 2 Фрагментах - sharedViewModel в помощь.

Comment: В диалоговом фрагменте viewModel не инициализирована. Спасибо, попробую sharedViewModel.